# Freezing issues every time I run Xorg/startx (fglrx: No matching Device/Segmentation fault)

Tags: 14.04, server, xorg, fglrx, segmentation-fault

I've just spent the last 3 days straight with no sleep attempting to get my first mining rig up and running, and I've well and truly hit a brick wall.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04. This is basically my first attempt at using Linux, but I'm relatively technically minded and have made some great progress learning this stuff over the last fortnight or so. I'm also using ASUS R7 370's (4 GB). I've got four of them, but only have the one plugged in while I get it running right. I have had a few plugged in during various stages of testing.

The few, simple things I have done post format.

Installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 via USB with only SSH installed.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install fglrx 

sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial -f
```

then,

```
sudo apt-get install xorg

sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

Changed to 'Anybody'

```
sudo reboot
```

Then I have run `startx`, and that's where the problem comes in. I'm getting a frozen, black terminal screen with a slightly different font and no response from my keyboard. The only thing I can do is hit the power button.

I've tried reinstalling the OS about 20 times with slight variations in setup to try and solve it, IE trying things like editing the `.bashrc` file with export `DISPLAY` settings, tried doing everything with and without running `sudo apt-get upgrade/dist-upgrade`, creating/deleting `.Xauthority` and `xorg` configs etc etc etc. No luck. I don't know what I've done different, but it sure ain't working.

Is anyone willing to give me a hand? If you need logs etc, just point me in the right direction and what log you need and I'll upload them asap. Any further info you need please don't hesitate to ask. I want to get this going ASAP! I'm close to throwing stuff.

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT:**

Turns out I didn't have to use the power button and nothing else. After I run `startx` and freeze the system, I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to launch another terminal, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get back into the frozen one, but this time it's not frozen and has an error log.

It looks like the errors I'm getting is...

`(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@2:0:1) found`

Then after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill it, it comes up with.

`^Cxinit: connection to X server lost`

followed by a whole lot of

`(EE) Backtrace:`

`(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X`
..
..
followed by 20 of these errors including other directories (/usr/lib/, /lib/)

Then

`(EE) Segmenation fault at address 0x0`

Fatal server error:

`(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting.`

I hope this helps!

LOGS PROVIDED:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Ubkp3yax6HT0ZiS0FReVhEN1U/view
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ubkp3yax6HMnIyZDNRdzZUSWM